# Changing InDesign Master Text Size After the Fact

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I am just wondering (if u dont mind helping me with a question)......if I create a master page, and then I edit the text in the actual page (therefore overriding it), and then go back to the master page, and change the text size of that box, it doesnt change the text I changed.

Is there a way to do this? For instance I may want to change the text size or things in a template at a later date. If I apply the master to all the pages after, I would have to re-enter in all the data/content all over again.

Because I am creating a PDF of a company's brochure but the size of the product pages may need to be changed later. If I want to do this, all the data would need to be reentered. So I think there must be a way but I just started using it a few days ago.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks. So if I help other people (well I hope I can but assumed most people would know more than I who come here) my questions are more likely to get answered?

Comment: Eh? Where did you get that idea? If helps, of course, to be a regular of this site and have a high reputation, but anyone can get their questions answered here. Rep is just the game aspect of the site.

Comment: Thanks.

I am involved in some other sites (language based) that works on kind of a karma system. The more you help people the higher your rank, so when you ask a question its higher up the top of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Set up Character Styles or Paragraph Styles to handle this. Then when you need to update the font/size/leading/spacing/etc., go to the appropriate Character or Paragraph style and make the changes. Everything in your document using that Character or Paragraph Style will then be updated with your changes (assuming you're not overriding them locally - i.e. styling the text via selection and changing character/paragraph properties on the selection instead of applying a Character or Paragraph style). Read through InDesign's User Guide for more details on how this works.

Comment: thanks for that info. I will read up on that and hopefully I can do that with your helpful advice :)

Comment: Thank you so much @bemdesign :) It works a charm.

And I also realised this can be used in AI as well. I have used AI for many years and didnt even know about it hah. Going to save me a lot of time.